# Guide to using embedded resources w/ ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am looking for a guide to use embedded resources to hold a SQL script and then executing it via some execute reader call in C#. Does anyone have a good resource to read up on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very easy.

1. Create the script as a file (MyScript.sql)
2. Open the project properties (right-click project, choose "Properties")
3. Go to the "Resources" tab
4. Create a resource file if it doesn't already exist
5. The dropdown probably says "Strings". Change it to "Files"
6. Use "Add Existing File" to add the file you created

You're pretty much done. Your resource will be available, as a string, named *namespace*.Properties.Resources.MyScript. Simply use it as the `CommandText` property of your `SqlCommand`, `OleDbCommand`, etc.

Comment: How do you deal with embedded newlines in the script?  I'm doing exactly this and the resulting string has a bunch of `\r\n` embedded so it throws an error when I try to execute is as a `SqlCommand`.